# Has Ramaswamy laid out the constitutional and statutory authority the US president has?

Tags: united-states, constitution, reference-request

[As reported July 20, 2023](https://www.wmur.com/article/ramaswamy-government-agencies-nh-town-hall/44605624), Republican presidential candidate Vivek Ramaswamy, at a town hall in Manchester, NH,

> “Next week, I will lay out the constitutional and statutory authority that the US president has as the duly elected president to actually [implement the proposed changes],” he said.

Has Ramaswamy laid out the constitutional and statutory authority the US president has? And, if so, what is it?

Comment: Variations on multiple searches provided no usable information.

Comment: To implement what proposed changes?

Comment: @phoog - The numerous changes quoted earlier in the article, including shutting down the administrative state, defunding "two-letter agencies abroad", etc. Basically, all said or implied by his statements "and to do it without asking Congress for either permission or for forgiveness".

Comment: NYTimes [Fact-Checking Vivek Ramaswamy on the Campaign Trail](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/08/26/us/politics/vivek-ramaswamy-2024-campaign-fact-check.html)

Comment: The media has been saying that Ramaswamy is the most Trump-like of the candidates. So no surprise that he doesn't come through on promises like this. Remember when Trump revealed his ObamaCare replacement, it was a one-page summary?

Comment: All relevant information from the OP should go in the question not in comments.

Answer (score 3):

> **Question:**
>
> Has Ramaswamy laid out the constitutional and statutory authority the US president has? And, if so, what is it?

No,  he hasn't.   How can he explain the statutory authority for the President to change the constitution when none exists?

His desire to rescind birth-right citizenship would take a change to the Constitution.  As would his desire to change the voting age from 18 to 25.  As would his desire to give a citizenship test to young voters.   These things would take a super 2/3rds majority in both Houses of congress and then need to be ratified by three-fourths of the State legislatures, or three-fourths of conventions called in each State for ratification.   You know who doesn't have a statutory authority role in that process?  The President.

His ideas are not serious.  They're silly.

- He says he want's to be a bridge to bring young people into the GOP, while he also is proposing raising the voting age to 25 and making young people pass a citizenship test which clearly Mr. Ramaswamy would struggle with.
- He say's he identifies as a Christian Nationalist,  but he's a practicing Hindu?
- He say's he "unapologetically pro American" but then he says he want's to withdraw from our most important allies NATO, Japan, Australia, and Taiwan and then wants to bring our foreign policy more in line with India?
- My personal favorite was when he was praising the Constitution.   The U.S. Constitution is a perfect document, he says.  It's what allowed us to win the war of Independence.  The U.S. War of independence ended September 3, 1783.    The US Constitution was still being written in 1787, ratified in 1788, and went into effect in 1789.
- Wants to protect the majority from the tyranny of the minority?  Does he understand what a Republic is?   Republics were created to protect minorities from the tyranny of the majority.   The majority killed Socrates, so his student Plato created the Republic with checks and balances and separation of powers to protect minority rights.  His statements are ignorant and frankly more than a little scary.

Comment: None of the items raised in the article cited in the question were mentioned in this answer. While I appreciate a good rant, this does not answer the question. Even the "No" needs to be "Not yet". Though, I agree with an earlier comment that no explanation will be forthcoming.

Comment: (1/3) To "rescind birth-right citizenship [for illegal aliens]" does not require a Constitutional amendment. In [*United States v. Wong Kim Ark*, 169 U.S. 649 (1898)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/169/649/), the Court used an extra-Constitutional argument, "The interpretation of the Constitution of the United States is necessarily influenced by the fact that its provisions are framed in the language of the English common law, and are to be read in the light of its history." Congress can ignore that argument. It simply chose to not do so.

Comment: (2/3) The key provision of the Fourteenth Amendment that could be changed is, "subject to the jurisdiction thereof". Congress could amend [8 U.S. Code § 1401](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1401) (a) to define the term to include children born to "citizens of the United States and permanent resident aliens residing in the United States". This example would exclude children born to asylum seekers, visa holders, and those without documents, as well as those of foreign diplomats. The difference between "rescind" and "end". for birthright citizenship would be an effective date.

Comment: (3/3) Although the president might try to change "subject to the jurisdiction thereof" by executive order, I cannot imagine that would survive for long.

Comment: The first two paragraphs are useful in answering the question. The rant afterwards is interesting to read, but off-topic and out of SE rules, so it should be removed.

Comment: He's stated he favors a constitutional amendment to end Birthright Citizenship, so as crazy as his other claims are, he's not saying he'll do that unilaterally as president. So there are some crazy theories he doesn't support...

Comment: @bharring,  Ramaswamy has amazingly accumulated 9% support inside the Republican Party.   A 2020 Gallop poll said about 25% of Americans self identify as Republicans.  Which means Ramaswamy currently enjoys about 2% of the voting electorate support.  And he's proposing multiple Constitutional Amendments?  That is the definition of crazy.   Likewise using his campaign to concentrate on positions which the Constitution does not allow, rather than telling us how he would govern is also rather crazy.   I applaud his smack talking chops, but he's not a serious candidate.

Comment: I don't disagree with most of what you say. I'm not as comfortable dismissing him after the 2016 primary, but aside from that you're spot on.

Comment: @bharring I don't dismiss him.  He has a path to the nomination as narrow as it might seem.   I don't think his chances would be good in the general even if by some miracle he emerged from the primary.

Answer (score 1):

One claim of statutory authority was provided earlier than the Town Hall at Manchester, NH, noted in the question.

From C-SPAN, [Vivek Ramaswamy Speaks at Moms for Liberty Convention](https://www.c-span.org/video/?529024-2/vivek-ramaswamy-speaks-moms-liberty-convention), July 1, 2023. [All CAPS in the original with "uncorrected Closed Captioning". Emboldening added.]

> I WILL NOT JUST REFORM THAT ADMINISTRATIVE STATE. THAT'S IN MANY WAYS, A FALSE PROMISE. WE WILL SHUT IT DOWN, STARTING WITH AGENCIES THAT SHOULD NOT EXIST LIKE THE US DEPARTMENT OF EDUCATION. WE WILL SHUT IT DOWN. [APPLAUSE] THIS IS WHAT IT MEANS TO LIVE IN A CONSTITUTIONAL REPUBLIC WITH THREE BRANCHES OF GOVERNMENT. NOT FOUR.
>
> ...
>
> I WILL SHUT DOWN THE U.S. DEPARTMENT OF EDUCATION. I CAN TALK ABOUT THE LEGAL AND CONSTITUTIONAL AUTHORITY BUT THE NUMBER ONE OBSTACLE TO GIVE YOU IS CIVIL SERVICE PROTECTIONS. THOSE ARE NOT AN OBSTACLE IF YOU READ THE STATUTE CAREFULLY. THE **1977 PRESIDENTIAL REALIZATION STATUTE** SAYS IF IT IS TO PROMOTE THE ECONOMY, YOU CAN SHUT IT DOWN. I BELIEVE AN $80 BILLION SAVINGS BACK TO THE TAXPAYER IS PROMOTING THE ECONOMY. I WILL ACT ON THE AUTHORITY TO SHUT IT DOWN.

Not finding a "1977 Presidential Realization Statute", it appears Ramaswamy may have been referring to the "[Reorganization Act of 1977](https://www.congress.gov/bill/95th-congress/senate-bill/626)", which —

> Permits the President to prepare and submit to Congress a plan to reorganize any Executive agency for the purpose of improving the functioning of the Executive branch.

> States that no such plan shall take effect which is not submitted to Congress within three years after the enactment of this Act.

> Makes a plan submitted pursuant to this Act effective at the end of 60 calendar days of continuous session of Congress after the date of submission of such plan unless disapproved by either House within such period.

Given the act's limitations, only President Carter could have used the act.

[NBC News](https://www.nbcnews.com/meet-the-press/meetthepressblog/vivek-ramaswamy-lays-plans-eliminate-federal-agencies-fbi-rcna95409) confirms that Ramaswamy was talking about the Reorganization Act of 1977 at the Town Hall.

> Ramaswamy says the Presidential Reorganization Act of 1977 provides “an important statutory basis” to go forward with this plan, as it allows him to submit plans to Congress about reorganizing an executive agency.

The Congressional Research Service report [Presidential Reorganization Authority: History, Recent Initiatives, and Options for Congress](https://sgp.fas.org/crs/misc/R42852.pdf), December 11, 2012, shows that the Reorganization Act of 1977 was extended twice for President Reagan, in 1981 and again in 1984.

President George W. Bush requested reorganization authority at various times in 2002-2004. President Barack Obama requested the authority in 2012. In both cases, the authority was denied.

Comment: Minor nit, but a July 1 speech can't be considered the forthcoming explanation after a July 20 speech, technically speaking.

Comment: @bharring - I agree, but it goes to what has not yet been provided. The statutory authority of the president to reorganize the executive branch is granted by Congress and subject to rejection by Congress. IOW, there is nothing new to the claim.